# A question about cyclotomic polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

Let $F$ be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which contains $i$ and which, for every positive integer $n$, contains the unique non-negative $n$th root of every non-negative real number that it contains. Are the roots of all the cyclotomic polynomials contained in $F$?